# Rstudio environment

Tags: r

Please am firstimer with Rstudio. I have been trying to import excel data to my environment after saving the file as CSV. But I keep getting this pops up below.

```
Required version could not be found.
readlx 0.1.0 is not available
Rcpp 0.11.5 is not available
Check that getoption("repos") refers to a CRAN repository that contains the needed package versions.
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to install necessary packages: readlx and Rcpp and set the CRAN repo

Comment: What does `getOption("repos")` return? I assume this machine is connected to the internet? What does `R.version.string` return?

Comment: The machine is not connected to the internet at the moment. R.version.string returns "R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)". Thanks

Comment: Did you mean "readxl"? If the data is already in a CSV, you can just use `read.csv` without using any additional packages.

Comment: getoption("repos") returns CRAN "http://crab.Rstudio.com/"

Comment: Are there two typos? `readlx` (to `readxl`) and `crab.Rstudio.com` (to `cran.Rstudio.com`).

Comment: readlx and Rcpp

Comment: @Ahmed Please read the comments more carefully. It seems pretty obvious you have serious misspellings. You are also not telling this audience what it was that caused these error messages to appear.